# Duplicate inside dropdown menu

Tags: flutter, dart

```
var experienceYears = [];    

List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getExperienceYears() {
        List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = [];
        for (var experienceYear in experienceYears) {
          items.add(DropdownMenuItem(
            value: experienceYear,
            child: Text(experienceYear.toString()),
          ));
        }
        return items;
      }
DropdownButtonFormField(
   isExpanded: true,
   value: experienceTime,
   items: getExperienceYears(),
    onChanged: (selectedExperienceTime) {
      setState(() {
        experienceTime = selectedExperienceTime.toString();
      });
    },
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
     border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    ),
    validator: (value) => (value as String?)?.isEmpty ?? true
      ? 'Tempo de experiência inválido'
      : null),
```

Those codes give me:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: . 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
dropdown.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1606 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

Why do I have a duplicate? I make sure experienceYears differ from experienceTime variables, although they can have the same, even when I added != null before listing the dropdown items menu and experienceYears != experienceTime to ensure they are different.

Even setting toSet or distinct() at the end of the map didnt work, as far as I know those methods dont allow duplicates.

The debugPrints gave me this, which, is the expected result:

```
[DropdownMenuItem<String>, DropdownMenuItem<String>, DropdownMenuItem<String>, DropdownMenuItem<String>]
[Menos de 1 ano, Entre 1 e 3 anos, Entre 3 e 5 anos, Mais de 5 anos]
```

**UPDATE**: Problem solved adding the following validation:

```
items: experienceYears
                  .map((experienceYear) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: experienceYear,
                        child: Text(experienceYear.toString()),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: first check by printing the list in console if there is any duplicate

Comment: if `experienceYears` is a list of String, you can try `experienceYears.toSet()`

Comment: `experienceYears` is a dynamic list, should I explicitly declare as string?

Comment: @AnasNadeem I added your answer to my question. There are no duplicates and the result is as expected

Comment: You can try, if fails it would be great by adding printed data on question.

Comment: @Caio it's better to put your solution into an answer, then other people can more easily find it as well upvote it when it helps them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
items: experienceYears
              .map((experienceYear) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: experienceYear,
                    child: Text(experienceYear.toString()),
                  ))
              .toList(),
```

The validation above solved the problem. Thanks everyone for the help!